# grid mode active class add but click list mode active class not add in magento 2.3.5-p2

Tags: category, magento2.3.5

category page grid mode active class add but click list mode active class not add in magento 2.3.5-p2

> viewmode.phtml

```
 <?php
 /**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
    ?>
<?php if ($block->isEnabledViewSwitcher()) :?>
<div class="modes">
    <?php $_modes = $block->getModes(); ?>
    <?php if ($_modes && count($_modes) > 1) :?>
        <strong class="modes-label" id="modes-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('View as')) ?></strong>
        <?php foreach ($block->getModes() as $_code => $_label) :?>
            <?php if ($block->isModeActive($_code)) :?>
                <strong title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_label) ?>"
                        class="modes-mode active mode-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(strtolower($_code)) ?>"
                        data-value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(strtolower($_code)) ?>">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_label) ?></span>
                </strong>
            <?php else :?>
                <a class="modes-mode mode-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(strtolower($_code)) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_label) ?>"
                   href="#"
                   data-role="mode-switcher"
                   data-value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(strtolower($_code)) ?>"
                   id="mode-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(strtolower($_code)) ?>"
                   aria-labelledby="modes-label mode-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(strtolower($_code)) ?>">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_label) ?></span>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: are you use the custom theme ?

Comment: yes custom theme @madani